# jquery get certain class name of element which has several classes assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to read elements class name. I have elements like this:

```
<article class="active clrone moreclass">Article x</article>
<article class="active clrtwo moreclass">Article y</article>
<article class="active clrthree moreclass moreclass">Article z</article>
<article class="active clrone moreclass">Article xyza</article>
```

I need to parse out class name that starts with `clr`. So if second element was clicked then I would need to get `clrtwo` className.

Comment: This sounds like a task for `data-*` attributes/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match on the class name of the clicked item to find the class that begins with "clr" like this:

```
$("article").click(function() {
    var matches = this.className.match(/\bclr[^\s]+\b/);
    if (matches) {
        // matches[0] is clrone or clrtwo, etc...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for you:

```
$('article').click(function () {
    var className = this.className.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < className.length; i+=1) {
        if (className[i].indexOf('clr') >= 0) {
            alert(className[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vJfT7/

There's no matter how you're going to order the different classes. The code will alert you a class name only of there's 'clr' as a substring in it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to *find* elements based on these classes (e.g. doing `$('.clrtwo')`) it would be nicer to store the data as a `data-clr` attribute. This is standards-compliant from HTML5, and is supported by jQuery using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function.

In this instance, I would modify your HTML in this way:

```
<article class="active moreclass" data-clr="one">Article x</article>
<article class="active moreclass" data-clr="two">Article y</article>
<article class="active moreclass moreclass" data-clr="three">Article z</article>
<article class="active moreclass" data-clr="one">Article xyza</article>
```

I would then use Javascript like this:

```
$('article.active').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('clr'));
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/C3fPp/)

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the second class name which is of interest you can do this:

```
$("article").click(function () {

    // split on the space and output the second element
    // in the resulting array
    console.log($(this)[0].className.split(" ")[1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/Z3qhW/

Comment: Technically correct given the question, but far too specific to be useful for a more general case.

Comment: And, this assumes clrXXX is always in a specific position which isn't necessarily safe if any classes are dynamically added removed during operation.

Comment: Agreed, as stated in the answer this is only good "If it is always the second class name".

Answer (score 0):

Use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to get those that have class names that contain `clr`.

From there:

- extract the class name (string functions)
- analyze the position
- determine the next element

The latter two might be best served by a translation array if you only had a few classes.

#### UPDATE

I agree with **lonesomeday**, you'd be far better off using data-* attribute to handle such logic. Using CSS as JavaScript hooks is a thing of the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("article").click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('class').match(/\bclr[^\s]+\b/)[0]);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should jquery script should do what you asked (tested on jsfiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getClrClass(elem) {
        var classes = elem.getAttribute('class').split(' ');
        var i = 0;
        var cssClass = '';

        for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
            if (classes[i].indexOf('clr') === 0) {
                cssClass = classes[i];
                i = classes.length; //exit for loop
            }
        }

        return cssClass;
    };
    $('article').click(function (e) {
        var cssClass = getClrClass($(this)[0]);
        alert(cssClass);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4KwWn/

```
$('article[class*=clr]').click(function() {
    var token = $(this).attr('class'),
        position = token.indexOf('clr');

    token = token.substring(position, token.indexOf(' ', position));

    alert(token);

});
```